# Why's the big red stack trace error box still appearing when I use register_shutdown_function and set_error_handler?

Tags: php

I use both of them to handle all sorts of errors, even Fatal Errors. My callback functions get called when an error happens, but I keep getting this big red error info box with the stack trace. My visitors shouldn't see that at all! never!

To be sure, both callbacks return true. Actually that should disable the PHP's default error processing, right? But it doesn't.

I have a MAMP environment on my mac. Maybe there's some strange configuration that forces this error box no matter what I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to spend some time reading the PHP manual:

- http://php.net/ini_set
- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting
- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
- http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors

In short, you were telling PHP to display the errors. Since you removed those ini_set calls, they're not being displayed anymore.

Answer (score -1):

After I disabled these lines, that fat error box disappeared, while my callbacks still get called ;)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

NICE! (But I still don't get it)

Comment: I don't get what you don't get.